# I'm trying to filter a SQL dataset by today's date in SSRS using Report Builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS report that calls a stored procedure.  Here's the procedure:

```
USE [TSC-Telaid]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[TW_spRPTAllReceiverInventory]    Script Date: 10/4/2017 2:06:58 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TW_spRPTAllReceiverInventory] 
@SiteId varchar(50), 
@ReceiverId int
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000), @Index int, @Value varchar(500), @Source varchar(100)

SELECT @Index = CHARINDEX('Initial Catalog=', ConnectionString) + 16, @Value = ConnectionString
FROM CustomerSetting
WHERE SiteId = @SiteId

SET @Source = '[' + SUBSTRING(@Value , @Index, CHARINDEX(';', @Value, @Index) - @Index) + ']'

SET @SQL = 'SELECT R.SiteId, L.*
        FROM ' + @Source + '.[dbo].[vwReceiver] R JOIN  ' + 
            @Source + '.[dbo].[vwInventory] L ON R.ReceiverId = L.ReceiverId
        WHERE R.ReceiverId = ' + CAST(@ReceiverId as varchar)

EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

I pass in @SiteId & @ReceiverID on the dataset.  One of the fields I get back is DateReceived. I want to filter the dataset so that it only returns DateReceived = today() but it's not working.

I've also tried setting the filter expression to DateReceived BETWEEN DateAdd("d",-1,Today()) & DateAdd("d",1,Today())

I'm not new to SQL but fairly new to SSRS.

Comment: That's not valid syntax. Remove the quotes around the date part identifier (`''d''`) and change `today()` to `getdate()`. Alternatively you can do something like `...where DateReceived >= cast(getdate() as date)`. That will get you everything from the current date at midnight onward.

Comment: @Xedri the OP is using SSRS fucntions so `today` is valid. @drew jackson. Is your `DateReceived` column returning a date or date time?

Comment: It returns a datetime

Comment: @Xedni I tried that in the stored procedure, but it through an error because I was casting as date (or even datetime) and stated i had to cast as varchar.  That cast failed to convert to datetime from string.

Comment: Ah my bad. I thought this was just a regular old stored procedure. Didn't realize that was valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  I had to adjust the expression to:

```
DateReceived is between =DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 0, Today()) AND =DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Today())
```

This seems to be working.